# Add URL prefix to login_view

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am configuring an url prefix for a web the following way:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/myPrefix", static_folder="static")
```

Then, I set the flask_login values like this (which are run after the preceeding line of code):

```
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'auth.login'
login.login_message = u"Unregistered user"
```

When I access a page that required to be logged in, `login_view` fires. Then the problem arises: even though I set the `static_url_path` value to the `app`, and app is passed as a variable to `LoginManager`, the `url_prefix` is ignored.

Therefore, my question is: **how can I make `static_url_path` visible to `login_view` so that it includes this prefix to the login url**?

Comment: I don't know if you've already solved your problem but I wonder if what you are trying to do is restricting the static files from unauthorized users, in which case this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611671/restrict-static-file-access-to-logged-in-users.