# Is storing data in a JSON file safe (provided that it is encrypted)

Tags: json, database, security

I want to store data like users' emails and passwords in a JSON file instead of something like a database. The main reason for this is because JSON files are much faster and easier to read and update.

Also, I don't have good knowledge of how to work with databases :P

But, my main question is, is storing data in JSON files safe?

Comment: You *think* you want to store that kind of data as JSON. You don't. You're going to end up implementing a DB inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

Databases are more secure, but they also take more work (unless you already know everything about a database, you’re going to need to learn how to interact with it).

JSON is perfect for storing data and exchanging information at a server level. But when you want more robust, permanent data, I would advice you to learn using a DBMS.

The security related to storing data in a JSON file will mainly depend on your access control policy. Just encrypting or hashing passwords is not enough at all to ensure security. The file in question must be absolutely inaccessible by any other entity than your application. The implementation of such a configuration will mainly depend on the technologies used.

Comment: So no one can download my JSON file just like that? I'm using flask with python hosted on a Linode (for the technologies)

Comment: I have never used Flask but maybe the following could guide you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611671/restrict-static-file-access-to-logged-in-users - https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/explore-flask/chapter-5/instance-folder

Comment: Maybe you should just import sqlite3, which is part of the python standard lib. All the data is contained in one file stored on your server, and SQLite handles multiple clients with read only data very well.