# Restricting Access to static files on Google AppEngine with Flask-Login

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, flask-login

I am currently moving a Flask Application from Development to Production. The app itself is very tightly integrated with various Google Cloud Services - and is hosted on AppEngine. The Authentication is provided by Flask-Login and is required for every route (internal use only).
In the app.yaml file i specify the following:

```yaml
handlers:
- url: /static
static_dir: static
```

Which results in the files in the static - directory being served by the webserver and not by the flask process itself.

This results in a problem: Everything in the static directory can be accessed without authentication.

The Goal is to restrict access to the static files to logged in users.

For now, i see 3 options:

1. Remove the static-handler in the app.yaml and serve the files from flask via @app.route('/static/') and returning the file after enforcing login via @login_required.
2. Security by obscurity: rename the static directory to something hardly guessable
3. Leaving it as it is - not preferred / possible as some js-files are not developed by us and cannot be released to public because of contractual agreements.

What is the preferred way to accomplish the goal in an internal application, where no part of it shall be accessible without login?

How big are the performance impacts that option 1 will lead to -  as the app is running on a single F1-micro for now and will probably only be moved to a e2-standard-2.
Thanks!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611671/restrict-static-file-access-to-logged-in-users) for option 1. Luckily browsers cache css, js, and image files so I can't imagine the performance will decrease by a whole lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your 3 options:

1. This is a good option. You may be able to cache them, but you will need to set the headers yourself to do that.  Browsers won't cache them automatically.
2. This can work, but only if you trust your users not to make the obscure paths public.  You can set up your site so that that static paths are only ever served to logged in users.  Though any logged in user can see the static paths and could share them with others.
3. As you say, this is not an option.

Comment: Can you guide me to resources regarding your hint "you will need to set the headers yourself to do that"? Thank you!