# Flask - only allow file access to certain users

Tags: flask, flask-login

I want to restrict some files that are available to download on my flask app to certain users. When a user logs in, I add a session variable to show their access level , for example `session['allow_downloads'] = True` Am I able to use this so that if a user accesses [www.mysite.com/downloads](http://www.mysite.com/downloads) that it will check to see if the user has access by checking the session variable and if true allows any file in the downloads folder to be downloaded, or if the session variable was False then redirects or flashes a message to show they don't have the access. I'm not sure of this is possible? I can see a way that only allows users to access a file if logged in using flask_login [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611671/restrict-static-file-access-to-logged-in-users), but this isn't suitable as it would allow all logged in users to access the file.